# Java query with preparedstatement, works with insert, not with select

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, driver

When I use preparedstatement with an INSERT-statement, everything works fine.

When I use it for a SELECT-statement I get this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl cannot be cast to com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement
```

I did research before I started posting here. This should world, I also compared this source with different examples that I found on the internet.

```
private Connection connection = null;
private PreparedStatement statement = null;
private ResultSet result = null;

public boolean usernameAvailable(String username) throws SQLException{
    boolean available = true;
    String query = "SELECT Username FROM User WHERE Username = ?";
    try{
        statement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(query);
        statement.setString(1, username);
        result = statement.executeQuery();
        while(result.next()){
            available = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        if(statement != null){ statement.close(); }
        if(connection != null){ connection.close(); }
    }
    return available;
}
```

The database connection is handled by the constructor, and that works fine. That's not the issue.

Comment: have you gone through this?? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Very strange indeed. Maybe something wrong with the imports?  Try import java.sql.PreparedStatement; ?

Comment: try execute() rather than executeQuery()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to achieve by casting the result of `Connection.prepareStatement()` to `com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement`, but this is unnecessary, and is actually the cause of your problem.

You should never depend on any MySQL-specific class. And you should program on interfaces. `java.sql.PreparedStatement`, which is the type returned by `Connection.prepareStatement()`, has everything you need to use prepared statement.

Remove the cast, and remove any reference to MySQL classes from your code (imports included).

Comment: Thank you, it works, can you explain me why I shouldn't use a mysql reference?

Comment: First, because you don't need it, since all the methods you need are in the standard Java interface. Second, because the whole point of having this interface that is common to all the database drivers is to be able to use common code with all the databases without relying on proprietary methods, and to be able to change the database without having to change the code.